# move contents not fully completed

Tags: list, powershell, move

- I have a source folder called "aa" directly on c:\
- It contains 3 subfolders A1, A2, A3, with everyone a file t1, t2, t3 (respectively)
- I have a file called "mylist.txt" which contain list of folders I would like to move (in my case A1 & A3)
- I would like to move each folders listed in mylist, from source to dest, including their contents

when I try this code below :

- "A3" folder is correctly moved with its "T3" file,
- "A2" folder stay in source folder because not asked in mylist file
- but "A1" folder disappear and "T1" file is moved directly to "dest" folder...

```
#
$Sce = "C:\aa" 
$Dest = "c:\zz"
$files = "c:\mylist.txt"

Clear-Host
foreach($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($files))
{
       $fullline = $sce + "\" + $line
       Move-Item -Path $fullline -Destination $Dest
}
#
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I am auto replying to help any one
in fact we have to check if "dest" exist prior to move content, or create it
in this case all sub folder and content are move correctly
hope this can help
have a nice day

```
# PARAM
$Sce = "C:\aa" 
$Dest = "c:\zz"
$list = "c:\mylist.txt"
$line = ""
$fullSce = ""

Clear-Host

# --- DO NOT MODIFY BELOW THIS LINE ---

# verifie que le repertoire dest existe, le cree sinon
 If(!(test-path -PathType container $Dest)) 
    {
         New-Item $Dest -ItemType Directory
    }        

# deplace tous les sous-repertoires et contenus de la source vers la dest, 
# selon les criteres du fichier $list
foreach($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($list))
    {
    $fullSce = $sce + "\" + $line   
    Move-Item -Path $fullSce -Destination $Dest 
    }
```